# Stripe, PayPal, integration with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, rest, paypal, stripe-payments

I want to integrate Stripe, PayPal or Braintree into django project, and I want to use 'django-rest-framework`, now I'm confused about one thing and that is - Should I "touch" my database?

What I mean, I want only to charge once to my customers, it's a fee and nothing more, so should I touch 'db' or not? I'm afraid it will distort PCI Compile way of handling things. I don't know where to start beside documentation for those mentioned payments systems.

Can someone help me understand what are best practices for one time payment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm a Stripe employee, so I'll only talk about Stripe here.)

Stripe makes it easy to be PCI compliant. With a proper integration, you will never have access to your customers' payment information.

A typical payment flow with Stripe can be divided in two steps:

1. Collect the customer's payment information, using the prebuilt [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) form, or a form of your own using [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js).

   In both cases, the card information is sent directly from the customer's browser to Stripe's servers, which return a [card token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object). You then send this token to your backend.
2. On your backend, you use the token to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).

The token represents a card, but hides the PCI sensitive information (i.e. the whole card number and the CVC) from you.

You can find a simple tutorial for creating charges [here](https://stripe.com/docs/charges).

If you don't plan on charging the same customer multiple times (or if you don't mind asking them to provide their card information every time), then you don't necessarily need to store anything in your own database. When you create the charge, you will be immediately informed of the result (success or failure) and can take the necessary actions.

Comment: I don't planing on charging them again, just one time charge, thanks for clearing this out for me, now let's see what PayPal people have to say on this subject

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. If you did want to store card info for repeat purchases, or even payout info (like connected bank accounts for sellers), can you retrieve those tokens from stripe as well?

Comment: @sonarforte You can use the token to add a card to a customer object, then use the customer ID to create charges in the future without having to collect the payment information again. See https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later

Answer (score 0):

I guess you solved the problem.
On top of that, I wanna add some information about PayPal payments when working a REST API(DRF) and a frontend server.
In this case, you can use both servers to work to secure your transactions, how?

The frontend server will take care of displaying the PayPal checkout buttons, and creating an Order in the Paypal Servers when the order has gone through. And the backend server will check the validity of the order created in the PayPal servers (using an order ID passed from the frontend after the payment has gone through), and update the database based on the PayPal response to that.

Now you could simply update your database when the payment is successful, but that would cause a security issue: people can send requests to update the database without even going through the payment.
Here is an illustration of this:
[image]
Full tutorial: https://www.kowe.io/projects/accept-paypal-payments-in-your-vuejs-and-drf-app/